# How should useDispatch be used to enforce type checking?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm confused about the benefits of and best practices for using [`useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch).

Currently, I abstract access to my store (see below) by exporting the result of `bindActionCreators` which allows controlled access with statements in my components like

```
import {counterActions} from "./store"
//...
counterActions.reset()
```

with full type checking on arguments and results, and code completion on the individual actions.

But if I instead use `useDispatch` with

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
const dispatch = useDispatch()
// ...
dispatch({type: "RESET"})
```

I get no type or argument checking when I invoke `dispatch` and can easily enter nonsense like

```
dispatch({junk: "GARBAGE", morejunk: "MOREGARBAGE"})
```

unless I explicitly annotate in my component with something like

```
import { CounterAction } from "../store"
// ...
const dispatch: (action: CounterAction) => void = useDispatch()
```

or create a wrapper in my store with something like

```
export function useMyDispatch(): (action: CounterAction) => void {
    return useDispatch()
}
```

and then use that in my components.

Why is `useDispatch` better than my `counterActions`? Is there an idiom for the use of `useDispatch` that I've misunderstood or am missing?

---

**store.ts**:

```
import { createStore } from "redux"
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'


interface CounterState {
    count: number;
}

type CounterAction =
    | { type: 'INCREMENT'; step: number }
    | { type: 'RESET' }

const initialState: CounterState = {count: 0}

const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action: CounterAction): CounterState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state, count: state.count + action.step}
        case "RESET":
            return {...state, count: 1}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

// Use only for Provider
export const store = createStore(counterReducer)

const increment = (step: number = 1): CounterAction  => ({ type: "INCREMENT", step: step })
const reset = (): CounterAction => ({ type: "RESET" })

export const counterActions = bindActionCreators(
    { increment, reset },
    store.dispatch
)
```

Comment: (Clearly I'm doing something very wrong.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a typed custom hooks:

```
type Dispatch = <TReturnType>(action: Actions) => TReturnType;
const useTypedDispatch = () => useDispatch<Dispatch>();
```

where `Actions` is an union of all your available actions, like `CounterAction` in your question. You can use it as:

```
const dispatch = useTypedDispatch()
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do that over using `bindActionCreators`? That certainly results in tidier (looking) invocations: `counterActions.increment(3)` vs `dispatch({type: "INCREMENT", step: 3})`.

Comment: it's generally considered an anti-pattern to interact with the store directly like you are doing; one of the reason is that it make difficult to render the app on the server, https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself

Comment: but if you don't care about those cons, be free to use that; it only need to make sense in your application to make their use justifiable. but, in my opinion, it doesn't buy you much more than having something like `dispatch(increment(123))`

Comment: OK, that's what I wasn't seeing I guess (where is it documented?): that `counterActions.increment(3)` and `dispatch({type: "INCREMENT", step: 3})` are actually doing different things. I thought they had the same effect.

Comment: That works. I still am not clear why `export const counterActions = bindActionCreators ...` is an anti-pattern though.